# C calculate values with different datatypes

Tags: c, types, casting

I just try to calculate this on my microcontroller programm:

```
uint16_t aOffset = 0;
uint16_t bOffset = 0;
uint16_t a = 530;
uint16_t b = 530;
int16_t aReal = a - aOffset;
int16_t bReal = b - bOffset;
int32_t c = (int32_t) aReal * bReal;

printf("%d, %d, %d\n", aReal, bReal, c);
```

And the output is:

530, 530, 18756

But the output should be:

530, 530, 280900

What's wrong here?

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  This prints "`530, 530, 280900`" on my machine.

Comment: try `printf("%" PRId16 ", %" PRId16 ", %" PRId32 "\n", aReal, bReal, c);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Or cast to `long` and use `"%ld"`.